# How to check if a constant is defined in main layout?

Tags: exception, yii, constants

I've this snippet of code in main layout file (protected/views/layouts/main.php):

```
    <?php if (defined('YII_DEBUG')) { ?>
        <button id="search-hidden-button"></button>
        <script>
            $(function(){
                $('#search-hidden-button').click(function(){
                    $('#search-query-form').submit();
                });
            });
        </script>
    <?php } ?>
```

But I get this error and I dont know why:

> Use of undefined constant   - assumed ' '

```
    <?php if (true) { ?>
        <button id="search-hidden-button"></button>
        <script>
            $(function(){
                $('#search-hidden-button').click(function(){
                    $('#search-query-form').submit();
                });
            });
        </script>
    <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pressed a combination of ALT-GR + SPACE that your editor shows as a normal space but in fact is a special character that PHP can't decode.

This happens usually on Italian Keyboards, where "{" is printed with ALT-GR + SHIFT + [.
When you type really fast (as good programmers do :) you do like this

1. Press shift and ALT-GR almost at the same time
2. Press [
3. Release [
4. Release ALT-GR and SHIFT
5. Press Spacebar

Sometimes it happens that step 4 and 5 are switched, and you get your unknown character.

Remove all spaces in your IF statements and try again, it will be fixed (then re-space correctly!)

Comment: Thank you, but the code works outside the main layout. Dont work just in it.

Comment: If you cut and paste probably the hidden char is cleared. Try to type again the code, there is no reason that it would work outside the layout rather than inside.

Comment: Oops! Now works. Thank you again. Now I am able to recreate again the issue. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

No need defined again, try :

```
if(YII_DEBUG){}
```